# Regex to replace day by the previous day

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string `2020-02-24daily_report.xlsx` and I would like to replace the day only by the previous day. I think that the right way to do it is to the cut the string to separate the date from the rest, transform it into date format, doing a minus 1 and put it back with the remaining of the string. Any help would be appreciated. I am very new to regex.

Comment: You can't do this with just a regex. You can use regex to extract the string and you can then write a simple function that converts the matched string to a date, subtracts a day and turns the result back into a string to use with `re.sub()`. You should try that and ask again if you have issues with the actual program you end up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
items =['2020-02-24daily_report.xlsx']
for item in items:
    a = re.match(r'\d+(?:\d+-\d+-\d+)',item).group(0)
    b = (datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d').date()- timedelta(days=1))
    print(re.sub(a,str(b),item))
```

**Output**

```
2020-02-23daily_report.xlsx
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `regex` because it is at the beginning of string and it has 10 chars - so use `[:10]`

When you get `2020-02-24` (`old_name[:10]`) then you can convert to `datetime`, substract `timedelta(days=1)`, convert back to string `2020-02-23` and concatenate with rest of name `old_name[10:]`

```
import datetime

old_name = '2020-02-24daily_report.xlsx'

old_date = old_name[0:10]

today = datetime.datetime.strptime(old_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
yesteday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

new_date = yesteday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

new_name = new_date + old_name[10:]

print(new_name)
```

Result:

```
2020-02-23daily_report.xlsx
```

Comment: thank you for your constructive answers and not just a minus. I used the one below but yours works too.